# Can't install formatter while using python anaconda as my interpreter in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

people!

So I'm pretty new to vscode and anaconda, and recently I'm having trouble with installing the formatter such as "autopep8" and "black" in vscode.

Basically, there will be a window pop up at the bottom right and ask me which formatter I want to install, and when I click that I get two options:

1. Install using conda.
2. Install using pip.

And if I click "Install using conda", I get the following error message on my terminal:

> "Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed
>
> CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url
>   https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json
>   Elapsed: - An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
>   HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on
>   your way.
>
> If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please
>   file a support request with your network engineering team."

Is it because I didn't set up my Anaconda properly? Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So after some research, I found the solution to my problem:

The issue only occurs because I didn't set up my Anaconda environment **properly**/**at all**... Basically all I did is to launch vscode from Anaconda Navigator and it should set up everything for me...

For anyone who's struggling with this issue, below is the official documentation from Anaconda(https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/integration/vscode/):

> When you launch VS Code from Navigator, VS Code is configured to use the Python >interpreter in the currently selected environment.